# Cinema4D: How do I import/include/embed a user python script into another?

Tags: python, cinema-4d

I would like to embed a script file full of often used defs into other script files.
For example, I would like **test.py** to load the contents of **defs.py** (which is in the same folder) into itself in line.

When I try adding

```
import defs
```

into the body inside test.py I get error "No module named defs"

Comment: Add `__init__.py` a blank file in that folder, should work

Comment: I tried adding the init file into the folder that holds the two files but get the same error.

Comment: How are you executing the file?

Comment: With test.py loaded in the Script Manager panel I click on the Execute Button

Comment: @user2016210, did you ever solve this issue? I'm also curious.

Answer (score 1):

For anybody else facing this issue. Just add this on top of your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```